# Paypal Express Checkout: Mixed Recurring and Non-Recurring Items

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart, cart

I am working on our company cart which contains products that people can either subscribe to or just buy outright. The problem is that it should require customers to add both types in a single order.

Question: It is possible to to tell Paypal to charge selected items as subscription and the others as one-time payments?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for the question. I am having the same requirement and looking for the solution. Could you provide your sample code for the same. I am working in .net with c#

Comment: Hey!! Did u solve the problem? I am having the same problem so would u like to share the solution if you find one? I am using php btw.

Comment: The approved answer worked for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [advanced features](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_expresscheckout_advancedfeaturesguide.pdf) documentation page 47/48, this is possible by calling SetExpressCheckout with the recurring products as BillingAgreements and the other products as normal, then calling DoExpressCheckoutPayment if there are one-time payments followed by CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile for the recurring products (up to 10).

Caveat: This is a WIP for me, relaying what information I could find.

Comment: I believe billing agreements are set per transaction (via CMD parameter) and not per item.

Comment: I fixed the link to the documentation. Up to 10 billing agreements can be included in the SetExpressCheckout call together with the one-time payments. Don't start with SetCustomerBillingAgreement if you have one-time payments.

Comment: @Heine: Could you provide the sample code for the same in .net?