# How to handle recurring payments with multiple items in cart, including non-recurring items?

Tags: php, paypal

I am working on our company cart which contains products that people can either subscribe to or just buy outright. The problem is that it should require customers to add both types in a single order.

Question: It is possible to to tell Paypal to charge selected items as subscription and the others as one-time payments?

Note: Some recurring items could be on different billing cycles/frequencies than others.

Note: This question was previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194872/paypal-express-checkout-mixed-recurring-and-non-recurring-items), but is out of date.